# Redirect on .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the url

> X.com.ar/ucyg-test

(X would be a name)

I want to redirect to a subfolder, that is /Web

So when I enter in `X.com.ar/ucyg-test` I will see the .html under `X.com.ar/ucyg-test/Web`
(but as user in the browser I don't want to see that `/Web`)

I added this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^X.com.ar/ucyg-test$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^X.com.ar/ucyg-test$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !Web/
RewriteRule (.*) /Web/$1 [L]
```

but when I enter on `X.com.ar/ucyg-test`, I'm getting a 404.
Why this `.htaccess` is not working?
If I enter on `X.com.ar/ucyg-test/Web` is working, even if I don't have the `.htaccess`

**Edit**

After anubhava's help, this is my current `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Web/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(ucyg-test)(/.*|)$ /$1/Web/$2 [L,NC,R]
```

No `PHP` plugins or `CMS` installed, just pure `php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` represents just the domain name in the URL not the URI.

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ucyg-test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!Web/).*)$ Web/$1 [L,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Sorry, but I would like to enter to redirect to X.com.ar/ucyg-test/web when I enter to X.com.ar/ucyg-test (without seeing the "/web" on the browser).. This won't redirecto to X.com.ar/Web ? I think I asked in the wrong way, let me edit

Comment: No, still I'm getting 404 :/ I've replaced the X with the name, but when I enter to X.com.ar/ucyg-test I get a 404.

Comment: In which directory have you placed this .htaccess?

Comment: in the "/". I have "/", inside this folder I have some folders, including /Web

Comment: Ok just for testing can you add R flag like `RewriteRule ^(ucyg-test)(/.*|)$ /$1/Web/$2 [L,NC,R]` and comment out first `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` line?

Comment: Same result, a 404 page :/

Comment: Ok just below RewriteEngine On line add **`RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R]`** and then visit `http://site.com/foo` to check whether you get `http://site.com/bar` OR not?

Comment: No, I get 404 on /foo. It doesn't get a 404 in /bar (I mean, doesn't redirect)

Comment: That tells me that probably your `.htaccess` isn't even being read. Can you put same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generated 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: sorry, was my mistake on the upload. I DO get a redirect on /foo to /bar. My bad

Comment: It shouldn't cause looping. Q1) Post your complete and latest .htaccess in you question. Q2) Do you have any PHP/CMS framework installed?

Comment: Ok and do you have any PHP/CMS framework installed on your system? If not then comment all the existing rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line add `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /bar [L,R]` and then visit `http://site.com/foo`

Comment: I get a 404, but when I enter to site.com.ar/ucyg-test/foo it redirects to site.com.ar/bar

Comment: Hmm that tells me that your `.htaccess` is actually placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/ucyg-test/.htaccess`

Comment: maybe you're right; from the Filezilla I only see "/" folder (sorry if I didn't interpreate it well, I'm new on php publish)

Comment: It works! But the entire page is broken. I mean, the GET for the css and images and etc not working. I see that is making the request to site.com.ar/css/foo.css instead of site.com.ar/ucyg-test/Web/foo.cs (I'm not sure about the "ucyg-test", but the CSS folder is under /Web so that needs to be in the url)

Comment: Try edited code. Also for CSS are you including it like `/css/foo.css` ?

Comment: Still not getting images or CSS. Under /Web/Views/foo.html I have an include with href="../Css/styles.css". Css folder is under web, like /Web/Css

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39093/discussion-between-anubhava-and-gonzalo)

Comment: Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.